# Volume in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus

I have to find volume of 3d object bounded with
$$x^{2}+y^2+z^2 \geq 6,  x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq12, x \geq y^2+z^2, x \leq \frac{13}4$$
using spherical coordinates. 
I have problems to determinate what $ \theta $ is .

Comment: Hint: You're better off defining spherical coordinates by swapping the definitions for $x$ and $z$

Comment: I am. But still problems with $ \theta $

Comment: I have added an answer below that shows how to deal with the $\theta$ bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do this integral has to be split into multiple parts, but the easiest way to do this is spherical coordinates with the angular integral first. Setting

$$\begin{cases} x = r\cos\theta \\ y = r\sin\theta\sin\phi \\ z = r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\ \end{cases} \implies J = r^2\sin\theta$$

we have the following boundaries:

$$\begin{cases} x^2+y^2+z^2=6 \\ x^2+y^2+z^2=12 \\ x = y^2+z^2 \\ x = \frac{13}{4} \\ \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}r = \sqrt{6} \\ r = \sqrt{12} \\ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4r^2+1}-1}{2r}\right) \\ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{4r}\right)\end{cases}$$

where used the quadratic equation to get the equation of the paraboloid and took the positive root since we are in the "first quadrant" of $\theta$. The plane intersects the outer sphere but not the inner one, leading us to the following two integrals:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\sqrt{6}}^{\frac{13}{4}} \int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4r^2+1}-1}{2r}\right)} r^2 \sin\theta \:d\theta \: dr \:d\phi + \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\frac{13}{4}}^{\sqrt{12}} \int_{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{4r}\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4r^2+1}-1}{2r}\right)} r^2 \sin\theta \:d\theta \: dr \:d\phi$$

$$= \pi \int_{\sqrt{6}}^{\frac{13}{4}} 2r^2 + r - r\sqrt{4r^2+1} \:dr + \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{\frac{13}{4}}^{\sqrt{12}} 15r - 2r\sqrt{4r^2+1}\:dr$$

$$ = -\frac{\pi}{12}\left(4r^2+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\Biggr|_{\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{12}} + \pi\Biggr[\frac{2}{3}r^3 + \frac{1}{2}r^2 \Biggr]_{\sqrt{6}}^{\frac{13}{4}} + \frac{15\pi}{4}r^2\Biggr|_{\frac{13}{4}}^{\sqrt{12}}$$

$$= -\frac{109\pi}{6} + \frac{169\pi}{6} - 3\pi - 4\sqrt{6}\pi + 45\pi - \frac{2535\pi}{64} = \frac{793\pi}{64} - 4\sqrt{6}\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use a cylinder of revolution about the $x$ axis and integrate to find the volume between the planes, as shown above.

This side view may help:

[image]